# Individual fuzzy membership values of a crisp number

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy, fuzzing

Consider a trapezoidal membership function having values a, b, c, d. How can I define fuzzy membership function for four linguistic variables like {low, medium-low, medium-large, large} with a defined equation with all these four variables? In the case case of a triangular membership function with (a, b, c) I can define membership function for *μ(low)* as *Max{0,min((b-x)/(b-a) , 1)}* and *μ(medium)* as *Max{0,min((x-a)/(b-a) , (c-x)/(c-b))}* and *μ(high)* as *Max{0,min((x-b)/(c-b) , 1)}*.